# Calc/Spreadsheet: combine/assign/migrate cols

Tags: excel, google-sheets, openoffice-calc

Sorry, i can't use the right terms but i try to explain my task:

In Calc, or Spreadsheet I have two worksheets with columns like this:

```
|   ID|
|   32|
|   51|
|   51|
|   63|
|   70|
```

and

```
|   ID|Name     |   
|   01|name1    |   
|   02|name2    |   
...
|   69|name69   |   
|   70|name70   |
```

i need to combine/assign/migrate these together, like:

```
|   ID|Name     |   
|   32|name32   |   
|   51|name51   |   
|   51|name51   |   
|   63|name63   |   
|   70|name70   |
```

I have no idea how can is start to solve it. Please help!

Comment: In excel, you can use VLookup. Some good examples here: http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/lookup-reference-functions.html

Comment: Is the information on worksheet 2 in the form of a table or raw data, such as ID's in column A and Name's in column B?

Comment: @pnuts, Good one. Was going with the OP's terminology and assuming that the second graphic was what s/he was calling worksheet 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @PsysicalChemist, the [VLookup](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_VLOOKUP_function) function is working in Calc to.